# Is it possible to use Jquery sortable on single select?

Tags: jquery, html

The lists can be easily sortable so I want something similar where the options of `<select>` tag can be arranged as according to my need while still preserving the original functionality of `<select>` tag.

Is it possible to rearrange the `<options>` of `<select>` using jquery sortable?

Comment: Have you looked at combining jquery uis selectable and sortable?

Comment: All the documentation of selectable are also using ul li and that brings me back to my original problem

Comment: So convert it over to that format, it is not hard to do with JavaScript. You can not drag and drop option elements.

Comment: I tried that but it brings a bunch of other problems like not creating scroll bars when the list is really long and hogging up the page space, creating lists and what-nots.
 All i want to know is can sortable be used on select itself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some thing like this

```
    var options = $("#select option");    
 options.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a.text > b.text) return 1;
    if (a.text < b.text) return -1;
    return 0
})

$("#select").empty().append( options );
$("#select").val("");
```